# SOCKET PROGRAMMING PYTHON- Putting the server code on an online server

Tags: python, sockets, networking

So I have a **Client - Server code** in python and its running perfectly on LAN. I have this server setup on **AWS** and I have uploaded my **server code** there. In my client code, I have changed the host to the **ip-address** of the server online. 
Unfortunately when I run the server code then the client code, there is no connection established. What could be the issue ??

Here is a part of client code:

```
def starting_client():
sckt = socket.socket()
host = '172.31.32.226'
port  = 9090
sckt.connect((host, port))
while True:
    data = sckt.recv(1024) #Data received from the server
    try:
```

Here is part of Server code:

```
def SeverSocket():
try:
    global host
    global port
    global sckt 
    host = ''
    port = 9090
    sckt = socket.socket()
except socket.error as scktCreationErrorMsg:
    print(f"An error was encountered during Socket Creation: {scktErrorMsg}")
else:
    print("\033[34mSocket was created as succesfull\033[0m")
```

Comment: Content behind a link is not considered part of the question for purposes of determining whether that question is complete and answerable.

Comment: ...that said, at present, there's no reason to believe that the problem relates to the code at all, as opposed to being, say, a matter of firewall configuration. I'd strongly suggest ruling out the system-configuration issues (say, using `netstat --tcp --listen` to demonstrate that the OS sees a listen socket, and `tcpdump` to make sure that the incoming packets make it to the host) before asking on a site purely focused on software-development issues.

Comment: Another way to find out if it's a Python problem or an unrelated system-configuration issue is to use `netcat -l 9090` (or whatever equivalent is available for your OS) to make incoming connections to that port show up on the console. No connection received == the problem's not your Python, but the system you're running it on and/or its upstream network connectivity (whether the system itself has a local firewall, or AWS has its own firewall, or so forth). Only if the problem is specific to your code, and not general to all software that runs on your machine, is it topical in the Python tag.

Comment: @Charles, Let me check that out. But i can add an say that i have allowed two open ports for inbound connection on thé server. That's 22 for SSH and now port 9090. Thé SSH works since its one am connecting to with Putty. I believe then 9090 should also work.